Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a subgroup of a finitely-generated group?
It is well known that $\mathbb{Q}$ (under the operation of addition) is not finitely generated. However, a subgroup of a finitely generated group need not be finitely generated.
So I'm curious: Is there a finitely generated group $G$ with a subgroup $S$ such that $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23352/an-explicit-example-of-a-finitely-presented-group-containing-a-subgroup-isomorph

@EricTowers Seems to be an answer, not a comment.

I'm not sure what the policy is for questions here that are answered on mathoverflow, however if there is a simpler  example that is only finitely generated (not finitely presented) I would accept that as well.
